# Redis in PHP: keys "*"

Tags: php, redis, key

I have searched the Internet up and down, but couldn't find the command how to get all keys from Redis db in php.

Example: `$redis->connect` `$redis->hset`

When I type `keys "*"` in redis-cli, I get all the keys which are stored in db.

Output:

`tenshi@mashiro:~$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "Testserver"
2) "testserver"
3) "Server5"`

Now I want the similar command in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [PHP extension for redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis), then the command is `$redis->keys('*')`